# How to display text/values from API in html

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api, web

I have a web API which has two values and I want to get these values and display them in my frontend. I already have the backend (API) and the frontend, but I just need to display the values. How can i do that?

Here is a picture where I get the values from API in console.log().

[image]

Here is how i get the value in my frontend.

[image]

Comment: use {{objectName.propert1}} in html

Comment: is this really angular? It looks nothing like it, if you are working with angular, we use components and no scripts...

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post EFFORT and CODE, not PICTURES of code!

Comment: `$("#apidata").html(data.myProperty+":"+data.myProperty2)`

Answer (score -1):

The points you should consider.

1. The network preview is saying you have received an `JSON object` in the response
2. `Element.innerHTML` property accepts only `String` not `Object`.

So, you have to access the `JSON object` properties and assign the values.

Example:

```
document.getElementByID('apidata').innerHTML = data.MyProperty + " " + data.MyProperty2
```

Comment: Down-voters, If you see this answer is not useful, do justify it.